# How do I create a new line inside of a concatenated text in java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I have made concatenated text in java:

```
table.setText(num + "*1= " + num);
```

This is my text, so now if I want to add another string like,:
"This is the final answer"
but in a new line, how do I do it?
NOTE: \n simply doesn't work, as it just shows me an error tha it expects a semicolon.

I tried inserting the escape command \n, however it just said that it expects a semicolon at the end of the escape command, and if I enter a semicolon, It literally crashes the app.

Comment: how did you try to add \n ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do you could use String.format.
For instance: String.format("%s *1= %s%nNew line of text", num1, num2);
Everything after %n will be printed on a new line. %s will be replaced by the text in num1 and num2 variables.